# Why do we show that $m \subset n$ and not that $m \subset n'$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at the proof of the following sentence:

For any natural numbers $m,n$ it holds that:

$$n \in m \rightarrow n \subset m$$

**Proof**:

We define the set $X=\{ n \in \omega: \forall m (m \in n \rightarrow m \subset n)$ and it suffices to show that $X$ is an inductive set.
Then, $\varnothing \in X$.
Let $n \in X$.
We want to show that $n'=n \cup \{ n \} \in X$.
We pick a $m \in n'=n \cup \{ n \}$.
Then $m \in n$ or $m \in \{ n \}$.

- If $m \in n$ and since $n \in X$, we have that $m \subset n$
- If $m \in \{ n \} \rightarrow m=n \rightarrow m \subset n$

So, $n' \in X$ and therefore $X$ is an inductive set.

In order to show that $n' \in X$ don't we have to show that $m \in n' \rightarrow m \subset n'$ ? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but $m\subset n$ and $n\subset n'$ implies $m\subset n'$.

Comment: I see!!! Thanks a lot!!! :) @TimRaczkowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is what you have to show. But, since $n' = n \cup \{n\}$, you have $n \subset n'$. Thus, if $m \subset n$, then also $m \subset n'$.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-)